# REST_query_vars for users

Tags: users, user-meta, rest-api

I'm wondering if it's possible to make that code work for **users**

```
function my_rest_query_vars($valid_vars) { 
    $valid_vars = array_merge($valid_vars, array('meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_compare')); 
    return $valid_vars; 
} 
add_filter('rest_query_vars', 'my_rest_query_vars');
```

I tried to send request http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?filter[meta_key]=ids&filter[meta_value]=10,67, but I get all users in response.

Should it work for users to or is it working only with posts requests? Any other hooks for users to make it work?

Comment: `filter` is not a valid argument for the REST API since it was committed to core.

Comment: I see, I found another solution with Observables in my app to get value I need.